# Why are the time derivatives for the unit vectors $i$ and $j$ in cartesian coordinates $= 0$?

Tags: kinematics, reference-frames

As the position vesctor of a point P from the origin O, is given as **r**P/O = x**i** + y**j**, and therfore the velocity, given through differentiation gives **v**p = dx/dt **i** + dy/dt **j**, and the same thing for acceleration but the derivatives are now second derivatives respectively.

However, my question is, when you differentiate the expression for **r**, using the product rule, the time derivatives of **i** and **j** are 0. Why is this?

My reasoning is that since they define the ground-fixed frame of reference they are nontranslational and nonrotational regardless of the time, hence can be considered constant in terms of their direction orientation, and hence be independent of time, therefore equate to 0 for their time derivatives.

Is this reasoning correct? If not, what is the correct reason?

Comment: $r=x\hat i +y\hat j, \frac {dr}{dt}=\frac {dx}{dt}\hat i+\frac {dy}{dt}\hat j, v=v_x\hat i+v_y\hat j$. Where is the product rule used?

Comment: @Sam You didn't use the product rule correctly (or did mentally but assumed the time derivatives of the unit vectors was zero): $dr/dt = dx/dt \hat{i} + x d\hat{i}/dt + dy/dt \hat{j} + y d\hat{j}/dt$ and as the [answer notes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/526516/6634), the $d\hat{i}/dt$ and $d\hat{j}/dt$ are only zero if the coordinate system is fixed in time. So the question is valid, and your comment skipped a step.

Comment: you have two 4 quantities, the x and y magnitudes, and the i and j direction vectors, x is being multiplied by i, in your comment you have assumed that the derivative of i with respect to t is 0 as well, I think

Comment: @tpg2114 Oh, my bad. I have never solved questions with the axis being changed and hence always skipped that step while solving.

Comment: @Sam No worries -- just wanted to clarify! I do my best to avoid rotating and deforming coordinate systems also, so it doesn't come up much for me either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, we often assume that our system of coordinated does not change and remains fixed. However when this is not the case you have to introduce time derivatives of the unit vectors. See for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_force#Mathematical_derivation_of_fictitious_forces) in the treatment of pseudo forces arising in rotating systems

Comment: I see, thank you for the link as well

Comment: Sure, my pleasure